# MVC 5 Intranet Application - your connection to this site is not private

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I built out a few applications - published intranet environment - and all of them are prompting for a username and password in order to access the application (connection to this site is not private).

I am not sure if this is an IIS Setting that needs to be adjusted, I have tried adding everything on my end with the web config settings. Even explicitly turning authentication off and allowing anonymous users, does not do anything.

So my main question is could this security prompt feature be turned off through IIS since the application web.config is yielding no results?

I have the default settings that visual studio generates along with my database connection string.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's two different things here. First, the prompt is because Anonymous Authentication is not enabled. If you don't want any sort of authentication or authorization, you can simply enable that. However, more likely, since this is an intranet, you *do* actually want people to be authenticated; you just don't want them to have to "login". For that, you should enable Windows Authentication.

The second piece, "Your connection to this site is not private", is either because you're running on HTTP, rather than HTTPS, or you *are* using HTTPS, but don't have a valid SSL cert. The latter is a very common issue in intranet scenarios, since there's usually not a public domain you can bind a cert to. In that scenario, you need to generate a self-signed cert and install it on all machines that need to access the site. Alternatively, you can set up your own internal CA, such that you can issue and validate your own internal certificates.

In either case, the message is there to let the user know that communication with this site will not be encrypted, so sensitive things, like say a username and password, will be transmitted in plain-text and can therefore be intercepted by monitoring the network traffic. That may or may not be a concern for your intranet environment, but the message is not internet/intranet-specific.

Comment: I will pass along the info and try to narrow it down using this. I will let you know what happens. Thanks for the info